# Importing an app-compat v7 library eclipse project to android studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I have an Android application created in Eclipse, now I want to import it to Android studio, when I import project I get the following error

```
Project FinalProject Integrate:/home/vishal/Android_Workspace/FinalProject Integrate/project.properties:
Library reference ../android-support-v7-appcompat could not be found
Path is /home/vishal/Android_Workspace/FinalProject Integrate/../android-support-v7-appcompat which resolves to /home/vishal/Android_Workspace/android-support-v7-appcompat
```

and it is an unrecoverable error.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here's what I did: In the the `project.properties` file I deleted all dependencies, and while importing project in Android studio I simply followed the instructions (making sure the check box are ticked, especially the one that says add any dependency). And it worked.

Comment: Do accept your answer if it worked for you.Although you could also compare `build.gradle` file in both the cases and let us know what was the difference.

Answer (score 3):

1. Edit your build.gradle, remove the dependency of project appcompat-v7
2. In Android studio, Go to main menu, `File` -> `Project structure` -> `Dependencies`, click add icon on the right side, and add appcompat-v7 as a library dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Go down to the folder where the workspace and there copy the project to another folder, then open the Android studio as administrator and try again.